# .NET - Which system assemblies are annotated for nullable reference types?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-assembly, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to find the status of .NET system assemblies regarding the **nullable reference types** feature of C# 8.

Non-annotated code, or code written with earlier language versions will be treated as "null-oblivious", meaning the compiler won't generate any warnings regarding nullability.

This is really annoying when it comes to using system assemblies from a nullable enabled context, as there's no way to tell if null-checking is required or not.

Is there any way to check if an assembly is annotated for nullable reference types?

Or is there some official status page about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 16.10, you should be able to see whether nullability was enabled in an external assembly by using go-to-definition on a symbol from that assembly that you're using in your code. If nullability was enabled, you should see `#nullable enable` at the top of the file. This also appears to work in VS Code when using the latest C# extension.

[image: metadata view of nullable-enabled System.Console]

Note that in VS this currently requires disabling "navigation to decompiled sources (experimental)" in Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced.

As far as a status page--it might help you to look over [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2339) in the dotnet runtime repo, which outlines when certain system assemblies were nullable-annotated.